# Wordpress: ACF custom field in PHP include

Tags: php, wordpress, include, field, advanced-custom-fields

I couldn't find any help on Google but also because I don't really know how to address this issue in English.

I'm working on a WP theme with Advanced Custom Fields. I need one of the php includes on the page to be a custom field.

How do I do this? I tried this but it doesn't work? I am no expert in this..

```
<?php $search_form = get_field( 'search_template_include', 'option' ); ?>
<?php include('$search_form'); ?>
```

Comment: Do you have an example of what `get_field( 'search_template_include', 'option' );` returns?

Comment: The include function includes a php script with the filename specified. So if your call to get_field returns a filename of an existing php script then this code would be valid.

Comment: It returns just '' search.php '' (just the text, no quote signs). Wait let me get this straight: the output does work if I just put it somewhere random. But I don't get it to output in the 'include( )' part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me almost an hour, but this PHP noobie found the answer himself

```
<?php include( get_field( "search_template_include", "option" ) ); ?>
```